# Finding indeterminate limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

[image]Let $\lim_{x\to 1} f (x)=+\infty $ and $\lim_{x\to 1}  g(x)=0$.

I stuck finding following limits.

a)$\lim_{x\to 1^+} f (x)/g (x)$

b)$\lim_{x\to 1} f (x)/g (x)$

c)$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)*g(x)$

d)$\lim_{x\to 1^+} f (x)g(x)$

Comment: what makes you think any of those limits exists?

Comment: I attached the graphs of functions

Comment: What happened to $f$ to the left of $1$?

Comment: There is no information about it.

Comment: Then how could $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) If g(x) is evaluated very very Little right beside the Point x = 1, g(x) = 0, does the value 1/g(x) exist?

b) What is if a very very large number is multiplied by another very very large number?

c) Reformulate it as $\lim_{x \mapsto 1} \frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{g(x)}}$ and use L'Hospitals rule.

Comment: Why do you think $f,g$ are differentiable?

Answer (score 0):

The graph shows that $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ doesn't even make sense. Why? It's not even defined to the left of $1.$ A reasonable assumption from the diagram is $\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=\infty.$ In that case you really need to think about a). It's very simple. b) and c) are hopeless, for the reasons just explained. d) is interesting. The limit need not exist, or it could exist and equal anything nonnegatve. Just to give you a start, let $f(x) = 1/(x-1).$ What happens when $g(x) = (1-x)?$ What happens when $g(x) = (1-x)^2?$